# Duplicate data store on Mysql with multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

How to store a `multidimensional` array on mysql? I have the following codes,

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_POST); echo "</pre>";

    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $array = array('nama' => $nama, 'age' => $age);

}
```

it will produce:

```
array(6) {
  ["nama"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "batman"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "spiderman"
  }
  ["age"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "40"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "35"
  }
}
```

Store to mysql:

```
require_once('db_connection/connection.php');

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tanggungan (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $nama, $age);

    foreach ($value as $index => $value) {
        $nama = $array['nama'][$index];
        $age = $array['age'][$index];   
    }

    $stmt->execute();
}

echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

I have google regarding this and come out with the above codes but it will duplicate the data like below,

```
id | name      | age
-------------------
1  | batman    | 40
2  | batman    | 40
3  | spiderman | 35
4  | spiderman | 35
```

Apologize if I am using it wrongly or not the best practice. Still learning with web programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a better way to do it:

```
require_once('db_connection/connection.php');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tanggungan (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $array['nama'][$i], $array['age'][$i]);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}

echo "New records created successfully";
$conn->close();
```

Comment: may I know why I am getting an error `Execute failed: (1048) Column 'name' cannot be null` but the data is store on mysql. Is it because of the for loop?

Comment: Did you add another key to the array?